# List index out of range error for breadth first search function

Tags: python, numpy, breadth-first-search

I am creating a breadth-first search function that will return an array of shortest distances to all nodes in a network from a given node and then creates matrix of these shortest distances for all nodes. It works fine for smaller networks but when I try to scale it to larger networks I am getting an error that the list index is out of range.

My function is

```
def bfs_short(G,node):
    queue=[]
    visit=[]
    parent=[]
    for n in range(len(G)):
        visit.append(False)
        parent.append(None)
    queue.append(node)
    visit[node]=True
    while len(queue)!=0:
        current=queue.pop(0)
        for a in G[current]:
            if visit[a]==False:
                visit[a]=True
                parent[a]=current
                queue.append(a)
    distances=[]
    for n in range(len(G)):
        distances.append(0)
    for n in range(len(G)):
        dist=0
        current=n
        while parent[current]!=None:
            dist=dist+1
            current=parent[current]
        distances[n]=dist
    return distances

    V=len(G.keys())
    dist_matrix=np.empty([V, V])
    keys = G.keys()
    for k in keys:
        dist_matrix[k,:]=bfs_short(G,k)
    return dist_matrix
```

The error is:

```
<ipython-input-296-b89665c85020> in bfs_short(G, node)
     11         current=queue.pop(0)
     12         for a in G[current]:
---> 13             if visit[a]==False:
     14                 visit[a]=True
     15                 parent[a]=current

IndexError: list index out of range
```

It works fine with this tiny adjaceny matrix

```
G_dict2 = {0:[1,3], 1:[0,2,5], 2:[1,3], 3:[0,2], 4:[1,2,3], 5:[0,4], 6:[3,4]}
```

But it gives the error when using a much larger network. The network is too large (~2,000 nodes) to practically paste here but I'm not sure if a small excerpt will help illuminate anything.

```
network= {0: [1, 2],
 1: [6, 0, 7],
 2: [8, 9, 10],
 3: [4, 1, 5],
 4: [11, 12, 13],
 5: [14, 15, 16],
 6: [17, 1, 18],
 7: [19, 20, 1],
 8: [21, 2, 3],
 9: [2, 22, 23],
 10: [24, 2, 25],
 11: [4],
 12: [4, 13, 26],
 13: [12, 4, 27],
 14: [28, 29, 30],
 15: [31, 5, 32],
 16: [33, 5],
 17: [6, 34, 35],
 18: [36, 37, 38],
 19: [7, 39, 40],
 20: [41, 7, 42],}
```

Does anyone notice anything glaring with the function that would cause it to give this error on a larger network?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a numpy issue; it's just list indexing.  `a` from `G[current]` is getting ahead of list `visit` size.  `visit` is expanded with `append`.  You'll just have to throw in a bunch of diagnostic prints to keep track of the list size, and detect why it isn't as big as you think it should be or why `G` has values that are too big.

Comment: IE, Before the error line, add something like `print(current, G[current], len(G), a, len(visit))`

Comment: Your first loop creates a `visit` array that's as long as `G`.  But it looks like `visit[a]` is indexing with a number from one of those sublists.  With your example `visit` is 20 long, but `network[7][1]` is 20.  `visit[20]` would raise this error..

Answer (score 0):

As I read the code, this error can happen only if there is a node in the adjacency matrix with a value greater than or equal to len(G_dict2).

This could easily happen either if there is a node in the adjacency list that is larger than the largest key in G_dict2, e.g. if the largest node in the network is 2017, but there is a list `21: [2018]`, or the adjacency matrix has missing nodes, i.e. no entry for some node i where i < len(G_dict2), in which case the length of visited will be too short for the maximum possible node value.   You can test this with the following:

```
from itertools import chain
assert max(chain(*G_dict2.values())) < len(G_dict2), "You got an out of range because G_dict2 has a node with id {} which is larger than the range of visit (0, {})".format(max(chain(*G_dict2.values())), len(G_dict2) - 1)
assert max(G_dict2.keys()) < len(G_dict2), "You got an out of range because visit is constructed by iterating over the *number* of keys in the dict, but the node {} is not in the range (0, len(G_dict2)-1) = (0, {})".format(max(G_dict2.keys()), len(G_dict2)-1)
```

You could fix the issue by initializing visited based on the maximum value in all adjacency lists, e.g.:

```
from itertools import chain
visit = [False]*(max(chain.from_iterable(G.values()))+1)
parent = [None]*(max(chain.from_iterable(G.values()))+1)
```

Comment: It doesn't directly answer the question, but I should also point out that this is not the most efficient way to generate the all-pairs shortest path, which is what appears to be happening at the end of the function.  You might want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm .